# C# CommandLineParser

Tags: c#, command-line

Trying to use Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.CommandLine.  I figured this would be easy, in spite of the lack of documentation (that I could find).  Anyway, consider this little program:

```
class Options
{
    [Option('s', "srcSrvr", 
        Default = "PROD", 
        HelpText = "Source server name")]
    public string SourceServer { get; set; }
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var result = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
        if (result.Tag == ParserResultType.NotParsed)
        {
            throw new ArgumentException("Invalid arguments supplied.");
        }

        Console.WriteLine(result.SourceServer);
    }
}
```

}

The program won't compile since "result.SourceServer" is not defined.  Ok, then where is it?

Comment: What type is `Result`? You may be hiding it by using the implicitly typed var.

Comment: Also, this looks like the 3rd party Nuget package [Command Line Parser](https://github.com/commandlineparser/commandline), which isnt a part of Microsoft's namespaces

Comment: That's true.  There is sample code there, that does far more than I need but doesn't help me with this simple task

Answer (score 4):

Mark the `Options` class `public`. The default is `internal` when there is no access modifier, and so the `Parser` type, which it seems is in a different assembly, can't see it.

Comment: Making it public still leaves me with the question, where's my argument?

Comment: It's right where you put it: in a place the Parser type isn't allowed to see.There may be something else going on, too (I'm not familiar with this API), but this is the first thing to fix.

Comment: @user1443098 stop using `var`, let the IDE tell you the type.  It might shock you

Comment: Stop using var?  You mean go back to MyType mything = new MyType()?  I've found var to be a tremendous improvement on that

Comment: @user1443098 but this is not one of those situations.  You are getting an object back from `ParseArguments()`.  You have declared the variable a `var` so you dont actually see what type it is.  You are also claiming that the object does not contain a property that it _should_ have.  The most basic troubleshooting step is to declare that variable explicitly, (i.e `Options result = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);`).  If that still does not have the property you are looking for then you know for a fact you aren't referencing the right `Options` class

Comment: @user1443098 Only use `var` where its obvious (i.e `var DateTime = new DateTime();`).  When you are receiving an object back from a method (i.e `var someObject = _someService.GrabSomething();` you should never use `var`.  It makes the code hard to read and follow.

Comment: I think that might be a minority opinion.  I ditched all explicit types for var wherever possible.  Compilers' type inference is good and getting better (see F# where you almost never use explicit types).  For me, it makes the code much easier to read.  Sure there are a few places to be explicit, like when a method returns an object that you know is actually a specific type.  In this case the type is ParserResult.  but writing ParserResult result = Parser ..... won't make my code easier to read, and it won't make it work either.

Comment: @user1443098 so in your case you expect the return value to be `ParserResult`?  Thats interesting, dont you want it to be type `Options`?  That is after all, the class that contains the property that supposedly does not exist...

Comment: @user1443098 Please do not dismiss it as a minority opinion. You should use `var` for anonymous types or when the type being returned is absolutely clear from the context. In this particular context, it was *not* absolutely clear. If it was, you wouldn't have tried to look for a `SourceServer` property on the `ParserResult` type. It *will* make your code easier to read, and anyone reading the code will know what type it is, and can go look up the properties that a ParserResult returns.

Comment: @mason `var` is also useful when you're dealing with an Interface or something with an inheritance tree. This helps your code be more flexible if the base type changes later on. When you re-compile, the compiler will see the new type, and it's one less change you had to worry about. But this question doesn't have that situation, either.

Comment: @Joel Not quite sure I get this particular point. If you’re dealing with an interface, wouldn’t you just declare your variable to be of the interface type? Or if you’re dealing with an inheritance tree, the base type that you plan to work with? Anyways, I think our point still stands that just because you can use var doesn’t meant you always should.

Comment: @mason It was poorly worded. A specific example is to imagine you have a method that returns an array. You want to change it to return a List instead. With explicit types you have to track down every method call. With `var`, in most cases the code will continue to work after the re-compile without changing anything else. That's one case, where my earlier comment was trying to catch the more general problem. Of course, having used IEnumerable or IList in the first place would have also worked, but getting the right level of interface abstraction every time can be tricky.

Comment: I think we can all agree that if OP would not have relied on `var` they would have seen their issue much quicker.

Comment: @maccetura, that's not it. in fact, explicit vs inferred typing has nothing to do with the problem.  Perhaps I worded the question poorly.  This is really about the specific interface and where it returns the results I expect.  It just doesn't work like the examples for it.

Answer (score 4):

Got the answer (nothing to do with var, by the way!)  I need to cast the result as `Parsed<Options>`,  that exposes a Value attribute which has the Options instance I need.

Thanks everyone for chiming in.  I'm always impressed with the breadth of help I find here!

Comment: Actually, you need to cast the result to `Parsed<Options>` - a minor typo that cost me an hour - I'll still upvote you though.

Answer (score 0):

Your `result` object has a `Value` property containing the properties from the `Options` class.

To print the content of `SourceServer` write

```
var result = Parser.Default.ParseArguments<Options>(args);
Console.WriteLine(result.Value.SourceServer);
```